How to list installed unofficial packages in Cygwin?
I'm trying to install apt-cyg and other packages not available in the official Cygwin installer. Commands like apt-cyg install nano no longer throw error messages, but cygcheck doesn't show none of the packages installed this way. So I'd like to confirm if apt-cyg is installed or not. There was a similar question, but its answer just implies that cygcheck can't see unofficial packages.
As my project concerns Python, I installed most of my unofficial packages with pip. Still, even though I don't really need apt-cyg and Python has its own package management tools, I'm still interested in a way to list all the installed packages including the unofficial, not just those installed with pip, apt-cyg or any other particular package manager.

DO NOT USE apt-cyg. Use the latest version of the official installer downloaded from https://www.cygwin.com/.

@DougHenderson Answered by an edit. I my question, apt-cyg is basically just an example.

cygcheck can only list python packages that installed by setup. These packages often contain binary extension which require elevated privileges to install, or contain major, essential modifications to run properly on cygwin. The python packages you install with pip generally do not require elevated privs to install, and usually work "out of the box" on cygwin.
